# How to normalize the mode and respective bounds of the confidence intervals (percentages)

Tags: confidence-interval, biostatistics, beta-distribution, percentage, mode

I have a dataset of the diet of a species, with the percentages that each individual ate of each prey.
My goal is to describe its diet and retrieve the percentage that the species eats of each prey (the sum of all percentages should be equal to  100%!).

I retrieved the mode and lower/upper bounds of each prey by fitting a beta distribution.

I normalized the mode by dividing the mode of each eaten prey by the sum of all percentages.
**However, I am not sure how to "normalize" the confidence interval bounds.**
Any suggestions?

Comment: This is unclear. It would be better if you described the data you have and the research goal!

Comment: I have a dataset with x individuals of a species with the % in weight that they consumed of each prey type (e.g., squid, fish). The percentages of each individual sum to unity. My goal is to retrieve the general diet trend of the species.

Comment: Please add this new information to the post as an edit. We want posts to be self-contained, and comments are frequently overseen. Also add information like sample size, number of fish species, maybe a data excerpt. I have once in a time analyzed similar data using multiple correspondence analysis ...

Comment: I don't understand, I think all details are already described in other words in the first paragraph "I have a dataset of the diet of a species, with the percentages that each individual ate of each prey. My goal is to describe its diet and retrieve the percentage that the species eats of each prey (the sum of all percentages should be equal to 100%!)."

Comment: Sample size? number species? I cannot see that is included!

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough in my question, my question is not exactly regarding my analysis but more theoretical. I already finished my analysis which provided me with a mode and confidence intervals of the percentage eaten for each type of prey. I'm just wondering how one can normalize confidence intervals (since I already normalized all modes to sum to  unity)